# Getting clearer StreamPlot output

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

When I do a [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html)of a rather complicated pair of differential equations, it loses some details.

For example:

```
StreamPlot[{Tan[y - x], 2^y - 2 Cos[Pi/3 - x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Is there any way to:

- Change the color near each of the critical points to a different set of colors?
- Increase the level of detail near the saddle points and spirals? That is, add more streams?
- Any way to make a collage (for example, a landscape variant in order to capture more of the rich details and global behaviors of all critical points, including the periodic ones in this particular example)?

Comment: Look here [Basins of Attraction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/basins-of-attraction/24160#24160)

Comment: @Artes: Thanks for the nice link! Regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a lot of options in [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html). For example, you can do the following

```
StreamPlot[{Tan[y - x], 2^y - 2 Cos[Pi/3 - x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   StreamPoints -> {{200, {{1, 0}, {Red, Thick}}, {{0, -3}, {Blue, Thick}}}, 0.1, 10}, 
   StreamScale -> {0.10, 100, 0.006},
   PlotRange -> {{-Pi, 3 Pi}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 600] /. 
  Arrow[p_] :> {Arrow[p], Arrow@Transpose[{2 Pi, 0} + Transpose[p]]}
```

[image]

Here `200` is the whole number of the streams, `{1,0}` and `{0,-3}` are the reference points for the highlighted streams, `0.1` is a minimal distance between the streams, `10` is a maximum lengths of the streams, `0.10` is the lengths of the arrows, `100` is the number of points to represent the arrows, `0.006` is the size of the heads of the arrows, `{2 Pi, 0}` is the translation vector for the streams duplication.