# How to draw the image of a circle under the action of a transformation of the phase flow?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, dynamic

How to draw the image of a circle $x^2+(y-1)^2<1/4$ under the action of a transformation of the phase flow for the equation $\dot{x}=y,\ \dot{y}=-\sin x$? Here $\dot{x}$ means $dx/dt$. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

The following code shows how to plot the trace of a point under that action which may be helpful.

```
splot = 
  StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Manipulate[
  Show[splot, 
    ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
        NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]], Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, 
          {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], 
      {t, 0, T}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red]], 
  {{T, 2}, 1, 20}, 
  {{point, {3, 0}}, Locator}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Take a look at a related post [Basins of Attraction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/basins-of-attraction). I guess the both answers can be helpful.

Comment: @Artes Thanks! It's really helpful but I can not apply it in this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way is to create a `Polygon` and transform the vertices under the flow.  I used `NDSolve` to solve the flow for initial points in a square containing the OP's disk.  Then I made a listable `Function` that can be applied to a the vertices of the polygon.

Since only the flow depends on the time `t`, I used a `GraphicsComplex` so that the vertices come first as a list.  That way I can apply flow to just that part and wrap it in `Dynamic`.  That limits the updating (by the Kernel) to just the vertices (plus the redrawing by the Front End).

```
flow = Function[{t, a, b},
   Evaluate[{x[t, a, b], y[t, a, b]} /. 
     First @ NDSolve[{D[x[t, a, b], t] == y[t, a, b], 
        D[y[t, a, b], t] == -Sin[x[t, a, b]], 
        x[0, a, b] == a, y[0, a, b] == b},
        {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}, {a, -1/2, 1/2}, {b, 1/2, 3/2}]],
   Listable];
circlePts = With[{n = 100}, 
    Table[{0., 1.} + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}/2, {t, 0, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/n, 2 Pi/n}]];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  splot,
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
    Dynamic @ flow[t, circlePts[[All, 1]], circlePts[[All, 2]]],
    {Opacity[0.6], Red, Polygon[Range@Length@circlePts]}
    ]],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ],
 {t, 0., 20.}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate animation]

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using `ParametricPlot`, as I will show in code here below. Special thanks to Michael E2 for sorting out a bug and proposing polar coordinates. The alternative would have been to use `RegionFunction`.

```
Clear[x, y]

sol[px_, py_] := sol[px, py] = First@NDSolve[{
     x'[t] == y[t],
     y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]],
     Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == {px, py}]
     }, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}]

pos[px_, py_, T_] := Through[({x, y} /. sol[px, py])[T]]

pp[t_] := pp[t] = ParametricPlot[
   pos[r Cos[theta], 1 + r Sin[theta], t], {r, 0, 0.5}, {theta, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> {3, 30}, Mesh -> False
   ]

splot = StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

Array[pp, 20];

Manipulate[Show[splot, pp[t]], {t, 0, 20, 1}]
```

Observe that memoization is used to make this fast, that is why I have that seemingly useless line `Array[pp, 20]` in there. It ensures that once the manipulate is displayed it will be entirely smooth. It's not necessary and depends on one's purpose. I was initially worried about speed, but I am happy to report that with memoization in place it is not very slow at all.

Comment: Thanks very much! But why you write 'sol[px_, py_] := sol[px, py] =' and 'pp[t_] := pp[t] =' to define functions?

Comment: @EdenHarder This is a case of simple memoization to improve speed, read this for details: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/731