# NDSolve ensemble of initial points

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to illustrate how the differential equation depends on the initial conditions. First if all differential equations:

```
x'[t] == -p[t]*Cos[2*x[t]], 
p'[t] == (1 - p[t]^2)*Sin[2*x[t]]
```

Now, I want to put many initial conditions (x[0],p[0]) with gaussian ensemble around given point (x,p) - lets say 200 and illustrate how the position of those points changes in the plane (x,p).

Initialy it should look like this:

```
Ham[x_,p_]:= (1-p^2)*Cos[2*x]
ContourPlot[Ham[x,p],{x, 0, 2 Pi}, {p, -1, 1}, 
     ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle ->GrayLevel[0.1], Contours -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: its not clear where you need help, how to solve the equations, how to plot the results, how to generate random initial points, (all of the above?)

Comment: Mainly, how to visualize moving of those dots in time

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34837/how-to-draw-the-image-of-a-circle-under-the-action-of-a-transformation-of-the-ph -- my answer could be adapted by using your ODE for the flow and your points instead of the circle of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. First, we define the final time

```
tf = 5;
```

and we generate `n` initial points, according to a gaussian distribution with variance `sigma`, centered in `x0`,`p0`.

```
InitialPoints = 
 With[{x0 = 0, p0 = 0, sigma = .3, n = 10}, 
  Transpose[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x0, sigma], n], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[p0, sigma], n]}]]
```

The result is a list of `n` pairs of coordinates.

Then we solve the differential equations for each given initial point

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -p[t]*Cos[2*x[t]], 
  p'[t] == (1 - p[t]^2)*Sin[2*x[t]], x[0] == #[[1]], 
  p[0] == #[[2]]}, {x[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 5}] & /@ InitialPoints
```

The phase space plot (your code)

```
Ham[x_, p_] := (1 - p^2)*Cos[2*x]
cont = ContourPlot[Ham[x, p], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {p, -1, 1}, 
   ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> GrayLevel[0.1], 
   Contours -> 20];
```

And the animated trajectories:

```
Animate[Show[cont, ParametricPlot[{x[t], p[t]} /. s, {t, 0, ti}]], {ti, 0, tf}]
```

The result is

[image]

**EDIT**

To obtain the points at a specific time instant `ti`, you can use

```
Flatten[{x[t], p[t]} /. s /. t -> ti, 1]
```

to obtain a list of pairs of coordinates, and

```
Show[cont, Graphics[Point[Flatten[{x[t], p[t]} /. s /. t -> ti, 1]]]]
```

to obtain a plot like

[image]

Of course you can change the point style to suit your needs. You can also animate the plot, or show initial and final points with different colors.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your nice reponse :) but I want to have a group of dots on the picture, not lines - You start with a group of dots scattered around given point and then in some time $t$ You have this group in different place according to equations of motion. It doesn't have to an animation at the end. I just want a "photo" of this group - position of all dots in different moments of time. It has to look like a scatter plot

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich now I understand. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Here are your definitions:

```
 eq1 = x'[t] == -p[t]*Cos[2*x[t]]; 
eq2 = p'[t] == (1 - p[t]^2)*Sin[2*x[t]];

Ham[x_, p_] := (1 - p^2)*Cos[2*x]
pl = ContourPlot[Ham[x, p], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {p, -1, 1}, 
   ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> GrayLevel[0.1], 
   Contours -> 20];
```

These are the list "lst" of initial points and the solution of the equations:

```
 lst = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {10}], 
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]}];
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == #[[1]], p[0] == #[[2]]}, {x, p}, {t, 
      0, 1}] & /@ lst;
```

This is the animation:

```
    Animate[
 Show[{
   pl,
   ParametricPlot[{x[t], p[t]} /. Flatten[sol, 1], {t, 0, t1}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Classic", PlotStyle -> Red] /. Line -> Arrow
   }], {t1, 0, 1}]
```

Should look like the following:

[image]

Have fun!