# Reevaluation issue in Animate

Tags: animation

I have an animation coded like this:

```
plt[t_] := ParametricPlot[{Cos[s] + t, Sin[s] + t (t + 2 Cos[s])}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}]; 
spp = StreamPlot[{1, 2 x}, {x, -1.2, 2.0}, {y, -1.2, 2.0}, StreamStyle -> {"Line"}]; 
Animate[Show[plt[u], spp, PlotRange -> All], {u, 0, 0.5}]
```

Which works fine and runs smoothly. However, if I want a more fancy `StreamPlot`, dropping the `"Line"` directive so I now have

```
plt[t_] := ParametricPlot[{Cos[s] + t, Sin[s] + t (t + 2 Cos[s])}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}]; 
spp = StreamPlot[{1, 2 x}, {x, -1.2, 2.0}, {y, -1.2, 2.0}]; 
Animate[Show[plt[u], spp, PlotRange -> All], {u, 0, 0.5}]
```

The animation slows down significantly and becomes really choppy. I'm fairly sure this is because the StreamPlot `spp` takes a lot more work to compute now. However, `spp` is fixed and does not change during the animation, and one would hope that Mathematica can take advantage of that fact.

I tried a few things I could think of, but I'd rather not embarrass myself even more by showing those; suffice it to say that none of them worked. The advanced documentation on `Manipulate` talks about using `Dynamic` inside the body of Manipulate to prevent Mathematica from updating parts that do not need to be updated, but I couldn't get that to work.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to plot `spp`, and then animate `plt[t]`"on top of it", without reevaluating either?

**Extended Comment:**

Following J.M.'s suggestion, I just tried

```
plt[t_] := ParametricPlot[{Cos[s] + t, Sin[s] + t (t + 2 Cos[s])}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}]; 
    spp = Graphics[StreamPlot[{1, 2 x}, {x, -1.2, 2.0}, {y, -1.2, 2.0}][[1]]]; 
    Animate[Show[plt[u], spp, PlotRange -> All], {u, 0, 0.5}]
```

but the animation is just as choppy. However, if I do

```
Timing[Show[spp]]
```

I get `0.`. I take that to mean that showing the streamplot should not slow things down that much, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: It may be more effective to pre-calculate a list of the objects to animate, then use `ListAnimate` on the list. For instance, `ListAnimate@
 Table[Show[plt1, plt2[u], spp, PlotRange -> All], {u, 0, 0.5, 0.005}]` is pretty smooth. Alternatively, you could try and play with the step size in independent variable within `Animate` together with `DisplayAllSteps -> True`, and perhaps with `AnimationRate`.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about the workaround of using `ListAnimate`. The issue with that is that it may take a long time to initialize the animation, and/or it makes the size of the notebook (and later the CDF) balloon enormously. The advanced documentation on Manipulate talks about using `Dynamic` inside the body of `Manipulate` to prevent Mathematica from updating parts that do not need to be updated, but I couldn't get that to work. I'm certain that it's possible to speed things up, I just seem to be unable to figure this out.

Comment: The main issue here is that `Animate` insists on redoing the streamplot for every frame, even though that plot never changes. If I could find a way to keep Mathematica from updating this plot, things would be perfect.

Comment: What version and OS are you on? Version 11 on Xubuntu Trusty gives a relatively smooth animation. If need be, you could extract just the first part of `spp` (it is a `Graphics[]` object after all) and put that instead in the animation.

Comment: This is version 11.0.1 on Win7 x64. You mean like `Animate[Show[plt[u], Graphics[spp[[1]]], PlotRange -> All], {u, 0, 
  0.5}]`? That's just as slow as the first. P.S.: Are you saying you're not seeing a big difference between the two versions I have given?

Comment: Nothing noticeable. I'll try it on a Windows machine when I get the chance.

Comment: I just tried it on a faster machine, and the choppiness is much less noticeable, but still there. I think if you have a really fast machine, the issue will be less apparent, or even disappear.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34837/how-to-draw-the-image-of-a-circle-under-the-action-of-a-transformation-of-the-ph/34838#34838)?

Comment: No, I hadn't seen this. This is a great example for some extensions of things I'm currently working on. Thanks again!

Comment: As for timing the rendering of `spp`, you can't do that with `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming`, which just measure the Kernel time. Here is what I do: In one input cell, put `foo = SessionTime[]; AbsoluteTiming[Show[spp]]`. In another cell just below it, put `SessionTime[] - foo`. Select both cells an execute simultaneously. The FE sends the first cell to the Kernel; gets the output and displays it; then sends the second cell etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is simply that rendering many arrows is slower than rendering fewer lines.  Wrapping the `ParametricPlot[]` in `Dynamic` to isolate the dynamic updates will mean that only part of the graphics will be updated in the FE's workings.  Note `Show[Dynamic@Graphics[..]]` does not work; you have to have the structure `Show[Graphics[Dynamic@stuff]]` (or have `Dynamic` buried further within `stuff`).  Below I use `ParametricPlot[]` to dynamically construct the `stuff` to be plotted.

```
plt[t_] := ParametricPlot[{Cos[s] + t, Sin[s] + t (t + 2 Cos[s])}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}];
spp = StreamPlot[{1, 2 x}, {x, -1.2, 2.0}, {y, -1.2, 2.0}];
Animate[Show[Graphics[Dynamic@First@plt[u], Options[plt[0]]], spp, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 {u, 0, 0.5}]
```

The options `Options[plt[0]]` could be pre-computed and injected, but since in the above it is never recomputed, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Great, that does the trick! My problem really was to figure out how to apply the `Dynamic`. Thanks!

Comment: @Pirx You're welcome. Yeah, I think this problem & trick deserves to be better known.

Comment: @Pirx Here's an alternative solution, with a slightly different styling inherited from `StreamPlot` instead of from `ParametricPlot`: `Animate[StreamPlot[{1, 2 x}, {x, -1.2, 2.0}, {y, -1.2, 2.0}, Epilog -> Dynamic@First@plt[u]], {u, 0, 0.5}]`

Comment: Yes. I'm still at a stage where I'm asking myself whether I was just being dense and should have read the docs more attentively, or whether it's really something that's not easy to discover. For once, that's not even a knock of Wolfram; the functionality is so enormous that I understand it's just hard to document everything properly. But, specifically, how would I have figured out exactly how to use `Dynamic` here, from the built-in documentation?

Comment: @Pirx I figured out it a long time ago (in V6) by paying attention to what worked and what didn't and thinking about it -- and by a lot of trial and error, and rereading the advanced docs.  The generic tip I got from the developers was that the `Dynamic[]` has to get passed to the Front End. In `Show[Dynamic@Plot[],..]`, it fails in the Kernel, before it reaches the FE. Therefore you have to think of something else. Of course, "passed to the FE" is not the whole story, but for a simple rule, I get pretty good mileage out of it.