# Transform a region using the flow of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, regions, geometric-transform

I was looking to apply a nonlinear transformation to a geometric region, say a rectangle
to obtain a transformed region. According to the documentation for [TransformedRegion](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html), one requires a Region and a function. I am trying to use the flow (solution) of an ODE at some time $t$ as the function transforming the region. I am using ParametricNDSolveValue to get the flow numerically as a function of the initial condition at some given time. Here is my attempt.

```
(*Ft is the flow of the ODE at time t=1, starting at (a,b)*)
ODEs = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == Sin[x[t]], x[0] == a, y[0] == b};
Ft = ParametricNDSolveValue[ODEs, {x[1], y[1]}, {t, 0, 2}, {a, b}];
R = Rectangle[{-1,-1},{1,1}];
FtR = TransformedRegion[R,Ft];
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TransformedRegion::vfunc: ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],0,1,{{a$109714,b$109715},<<5>>,{0,1}},{NDSolve`base$109724,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolveValue,Internal`Bag[<2>],None,ParametricNDSolveValue},<<6>>,{},{2.}]}] evaluated at a list of length 2 should give a non-empty list.
```

I thought I could define some function:

```
FtF = Function[{a, b}, Ft[a, b]]
```

And apply this instead, but

```
FtR = TransformedRegion[R, FtF]
```

Gives

```
TransformedRegion::vfunc: Function[{a,b},Ft[a,b]] evaluated at a list of length 2 should give a non-empty list.
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate, nearly (even the same ODE): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34837/how-to-draw-the-image-of-a-circle-under-the-action-of-a-transformation-of-the-ph/34838#34838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `TransformedRegion` only accept symbol expression. By now we have to use `ParametricPlot` and `DiscretizeGraphics` to obtain such region.

```
ODEs = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == Sin[x[t]], x[0] == a, y[0] == b};
Ft = ParametricNDSolveValue[ODEs, {x[1], y[1]}, {t, 0, 2}, {a, b}];
R = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
plot = ParametricPlot[Ft[a, b], {a, b} ∈ R]
DiscretizeGraphics[plot]
```

[image]

Comment: That's so cool!

Answer (score 1):

A work-around: Apply `Ft` to the `MeshCoordinates` of boundary-discretized `R`:

```
transformedRegion[reg_, f_] := MeshRegion[
   f @@@ MeshCoordinates[#], 
   MeshCells[#, All]] & @
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ reg


transformedRegion[R, Ft]
```

[image]